# Position Can't Be Set As Center errors when using Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I've got the following JS:

```
var map = null;
var center_marker = null;
var zone = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        convert_address_to_long_lat("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500", function (point) { map = create_map(point); map.setCenter(point, 13); alert('test1'); map.addOverlay(center_marker = new GMarker(point)); draw_the_zones(point); });
        //map.setUIToDefault();
    }
});

function create_map(point) {
        var mapOpt = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            center: point,
            zoom: 10
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpt);
}

function convert_address_to_long_lat(address_string,callback) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    return geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address_string }, callback);
}

function draw_the_zones(point) {
    zone = new google.maps.Circle({
        radius: 15,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        map: map
    });
   zone.bindTo('center', center_marker, 'position');
}
```

I'm using jQuery for the event (btw).  I keep getting errors that the position can't be set as the center of **something**, it doesn't say.

Does anybody have any clue on what I am doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback from `geocoder.geocode()` isn't set up to properly work with a `GeocoderResults` object literal. You're treating `point` like a `LatLng` object instead. Reconstruct your callback provided to `convert_address_to_long_lat()` to be more like:

```
function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var point = results[0].geometry.location;
        map = create_map(point);
        map.setCenter(point, 13);
        alert('test1');
        map.addOverlay(center_marker = new GMarker(point));
        draw_the_zones(point);
    }
}
```

Notice I check the status of the geocode to see if we were successful, then retrieve the location from the geometry object of the first result. You should be aware that the geocoder can return several potential results from the address string you provide.

For more information about the `GeocoderResults` object [check out the v3 documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingResults).

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
zone.bindTo('center', center_marker, 'position');
```

You are binding the circle to a center_marker point, but you have set it to null at the top. Try making center_marker a LatLng object with something like:

```
center_marker = new google.maps.LatLng(53.145,13.438);
```

But obviously change the latitude and longitude to where you need it to be on the map.

Comment: I do set a value to `center_marker`, you have to scroll to the righ ta bit.